# Deserialize Soap response C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap, deserialization

I have some problems with the deserialization of my Soap response, i get an exception when try to deserialize with XmlSerializer class

**Soap Data:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <IsWmsLoginCorrectResponse xmlns="http://pehade.be/">
      <IsWmsLoginCorrectResult>
        <UserId>int</UserId>
        <LoginToken>guid</LoginToken>
        <ErrorId>int</ErrorId>
        <ErrorDescription>string</ErrorDescription>
      </IsWmsLoginCorrectResult>
    </IsWmsLoginCorrectResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**TokenInfo model:**

```
public const string DefaultSoapNamespace = "http://pehade.be/";

//...

[XmlRoot("IsWmsLoginCorrectResponse", Namespace = Consts.DefaultSoapNamespace)]
    public class TokenInfo : BaseSoapInfo
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "UserId", Namespace = Consts.DefaultSoapNamespace)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LoginToken", Namespace = Consts.DefaultSoapNamespace)]
        public string LoginToken { get; set; }
    }

public class BaseSoapInfo
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ErrorId", Namespace = Consts.DefaultSoapNamespace)]
        public int ErrorId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ErrorDescription", Namespace = Consts.DefaultSoapNamespace)]
        public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

**Parse Method:**

```
public override T ParseSoap<T>(string resultSoap)
        {
            var document = XDocument.Parse(resultSoap);
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            var soapBody = XName.Get("Body", Consts.DefaultSoapNamespace);

// Exception
            var tokenInfo = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(document.Descendants(soapBody)
                .First()
                .FirstNode
                .CreateReader());         

            return tokenInfo;
        }
```

Did I make the model correctly? Can there is other method to receive stream for XmlSerializer?

**Update: Add exception details**

System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00010] in :0 
  at DAL.SoapConverters.LoginSoapConverter.ParseSoap[T] (System.String resultSoap) [0x00031] in C:\Work\Projects\Apro\Other MDO\WarehouseMS\DAL\SoapConverters\LoginSoapConverter.cs:40 08-30 14:56:01.858 I/mono-stdout( 4702): System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: Please always include all error details.  If you got an exception, what was it?  On what line?  Was there an inner exception?

Comment: I added the exception details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the XmlAttribute(s) should be changed to XmlElement. For instance the UserId should be:

```
[XmlElement(Namespace = Consts.DefaultSoapNamespace)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```